# calculate variance within each block of an image

Tags: matlab

When I tried to calculate the variance of each of the block within an image, the same way in which I have tried to calculate mean, it throws an error like:

```
??? Error using ==> var at 56
First argument must be single or double.

Error in ==> @(x)var(x(:))


Error in ==> assignemt at 19
    varValues = cellfun(@(x) var(x(:)),b);
```

Could anyone help in this regard?

The code I have written is

```
clc;
close all;
d=8;
a=imread('lena.jpg');
figure();
imshow(a);
 b=mat2cell(a,[16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16[16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16]);
[m,n]=size(b);
[m,n]=size(a);
%calculate mean for host image
% for i=1:m
%   for j=1:n
%   meanValues = cellfun(@(x) mean(x(:)),b);
%   end
%   end
%   calculate variance for host image
for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
        varValues = cellfun(@(x) var(x(:)),b);
    end
end
```

Comment: The indexes `i,j` are not used in the `m,n` loops. Each iteration is the same.

Comment: I corrected it,but it still gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `x(:)` which is a cell. Try using `[x{:}]`

Your code does not run, the mat2cell-line contains two `[` and none `]` so I did not try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your image `a` is of type `uint8` and therefore `var` is failing. Try converting the image to `double` either by `im2double` or `double(a)/255`.

BTW, why don't you use `blockproc`, `nlfilt2` or similar functions?